# Scala - Anonymous class not getting variable of caller class

Tags: scala, class, anonymous

I'm creating an anonymous class extending CollaborativeFilterModel. I want to return matrixFactorizationModelMock in the train method, but it cannot be resolved. Please note that matrixFactorizationModelMock is defined outside of the anonymous class.

```
class CollaborativeFilterTest extends FunSuite with EasyMockSugar {

  test("Index mapping"){

    val matrixFactorizationModelMock = mock[MatrixFactorizationModel]

    //Start of anonymous class definition:

    val model = new CollaborativeFilterModel(){

      override def train(ratings: Dataset[Rating]): MatrixFactorizationModel = {

        matrixFactorizationModelMock //Cannot resolve symbol matrixFactorizationModelMock

      }
```

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

um, you should return `matrixFactorizationModelMock` not `matrixFactorizationModel`...